# SSIS 2010 Configure Flat File Source Editor for Polish Lanugage

Tags: ssis

I have Pipe delimited flat files containing data in Romania and Polish languages/characters. 
The first row contains the column_names in English.

I enabled the  "unicode" check box in Flat File Connection Manager Editor.  But the columns are displayed in unknown character(In Columns Tab).

I need to map this data to a table in SQL server 2012. But in the OLE DB Editor, I am getting the same single column as "Available Input Column"enter image description here

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the source file using a file editor like Notepad++

The editor will tell you which codepage has been used

[image]

In your Flatfile Connection use the codepage displayed

Answer (score 0):

Source setting: 
In Import export wizard, when you select flat file; set Code page: UTF - 8

Destination setting:
Click Edit Mapping, and while mapping, flat file column with table column, choose destination column Type as nvarchar for required columns.

Run the package (or Click Preview) and check the table data, it should work.